# Hide products with no images on frontend

Tags: magento2, attributes

Is it possible to programmatically hide products on the front end that has no image?

Running Magento 2.3.

Answer (score -1):

You can create two plugin one for "**Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer**" and another for "**Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar**" as describe below to Hide products with no images on frontend

**step 1)** Create a **di.xml** under ***/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/***

File : **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
        <plugin name="custom_product_model_layer" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Layer" />
    </type>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="custom_product_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Toolbar" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**step 2)** create **Layer.php** under ***/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/***

File : **Layer.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer as CatalogLayer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;

class Layer
{

     public function aroundgetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        $collection = $proceed();        
        $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => ''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => null));
        return $collection;
    }   

}
```

**step 3)** create **Toolbar.php** under ***/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/***

File : **Toolbar.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;

class Toolbar
{


public function aroundgetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        $collection = $proceed();        
        $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => ''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => null));
        return $collection;
    }    


}
```

**step 4:** Run Below CLI commands

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I assume your using a custom Magento 2 Extension name "Vendor_Module" to do the above task.
If you are not familiar with how to create custom extension in Magento 2 then you can check this link https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-modules/ to create a custom extenstion in magento 2.

Comment: Thank you, i will give it a read shortly and test it out.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something, i've followed all the steps as above and on the link shared when running setup:di:compile I'm getting an error

    In PluginList.php line 182:

    Plugin class Terabyte\NoImageHide\Plugin\Toolbar doesn't exist

Comment: Can you help me with this please?

Comment: You may not create the Class Terabyte\NoImageHide\Plugin\Toolbar. Please crate the class as described in my answer and change the namespace to    Terabyte\NoImageHide\Model\Plugin;

Comment: I have followed every part of your guidance, for example in layer.php the first part of the code is:

namespace Terabyte\NoImageHide\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer as CatalogLayer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;

Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes. It's correct. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes, the plugin class does not exist. Am i making a mistake in di.xml on these lines:

1.        <plugin name="custom_product_model_layer" type="Terabyte\NoImage\Model\Plugin\Layer" />
 
2.         <plugin name="custom_product_toolbar" type="Terabyte\NoImageHide\Model\Plugin\Toolbar" />

Do i need to change custom_product_model_layer / toolber to something else?

Comment: Any idea Pritam? :)

Comment: @MehdiRafiai No, you need not to change the name "custom_product_model_layer". This is just name of the plugin but make sure plugin name should be unique. Thanks

Comment: It does not apply on pagination & filter item count.